# ¿Qué significa el simbolo ( ) en una lista intensional de haskell?

Tags: lista, operador, haskell

Soy nuevo es haskell y estaba viendo este código que comprueba si un número es primo, para ello usa una lista intensional con los divisores de x y comprueba la longitud. Si es par, devuelve true.

```
 module IsPrime where
            isPrime :: Int -> Bool
            isPrime x 
                | x== 1 = True
                |otherwise =  length [() | y <-[1..x], mod x y == 0] == 2
```

Sin embargo, cuando crea la lista lo hace usando ( ) y no entiendo qué significa.
Además, no entiendo por qué no usa un if para comprobar la longitud y luego devolver true o false.
Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empezando por el final el símbolo `()` indica un elemento de tipo `Unit` que sólo tiene un valor. Lo normal es usarlo para indicar que no nos interesa el valor que tenga o el valor que retorne una función.

Sobre lo de usar un `if then else`, piensa que en haskell no se trata de una estructura, como tienen otros lenguajes, sino que es una expresión que se "evalúa". Tiene poco sentido hacer algo así:

```hs
x = if valor then True else False
```

Directamente, podrías asignar el `valor` a `x`:

```hs
x = valor
```

En cuanto a mejorar el código, ya que tú controlas los límites de la lista de divisores, puedes hacerlo mejor de este modo:

```hs
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime x 
  | x == 1 = True
  | otherwise =  all noDivisor [2..(x-1)]
     where noDivisor y = mod x y == 0
```

Como la lista será vacía si el elemento de inicio es mayor que el del final, no haría falta evaluar el caso especial y reducir la función a:

```hs
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime x = all noDivisor [2..(x-1)]
  where noDivisor y = mod x y == 0
```

O rescribirla más compacta, aunque menos legible si aún estás empezando con haskell. No te preocupes ahora si no la entiendes:

```hs
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime x = any (!=0) $ map (mod x) [2..(x-1)]
```

`map (mod x) [2..(x-1)]` aplicaría `mod x y` a todos los divisores

`any (!=0)` comprobaría si en el cálculo anterior hay alguno que no haya dado cero (o sea, que divida a `x`).

Comment: Entonces como en este caso lo que me interesa es conocer la longitud de la lista pero no sus elementos uso ( ) ¿Lo he entendido bien?

Comment: Así es, Pero ten en cuenta que no es obligado, es solo una convención. Cualquier otra cosa valdría, por ejemplo poniendo un entero cualquiera, Sólo te interesa la longitud, no los valores.

Answer (score -1):

Esta función está usando una lista intensional para generar las divisiones entre el número dado y sus divisores. La lista intensional utiliza ( ) como elemento para generar la lista. Esto significa que la lista intensional está generando elementos vacíos, pero que aún se evalúan como verdaderos. En lugar de usar un if para comprobar la longitud de la lista, el código está usando "length" para determinar cuántos elementos hay en la lista. Si la lista tiene exactamente dos elementos, entonces en teoría el número es primo.

Comment: Relacionado [cheatGPT (chatGPT) nos ha alcanzado en SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes)